# Vaadin Grid : How to remove select/deselect checkbox in header?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin-grid

I'm using Grid (multiselect mode) in Vaadin for data representation and i've got a question:

How to remove select/deselect checkbox in header?

Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use css to hide it, something like

```
.v-grid-select-all-checkbox {
    display: none;
}
```

should work.

If course the checkbox is still there so by using browser's developer tools it's possible to make it visible.

Comment: Thank you! But in this case listener for this cell continues to run and successfully handles events ((( How to stop the listener?

Comment: is this .v-grid-select-all-checkbox class still used in Vaadin 23+? I don't find any specific classes anymore which are applied to this checkbox so I can't find a way to style them (I don't want to hide them, just style them)

Answer (score 3):

In order to avoid mouse clicks on the cell to toggle the checkboxes you can use the CSS property *pointer-events*.

I've added the style *hide-checkbox* to my grid and then used the following css to hide the checkbox and prevent click events (Vaadin 7):

```
.v-grid-hide-checkbox th .v-grid-select-all-checkbox {
  display: none;
}

.v-grid-hide-checkbox th:first-child {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```